# Can non differential functions become differential?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I was told by my maths teacher that functions having **sharp corners** are non - differentiable at that point.

Now what I understand from being *non - differentiable* at a point here is that the slopes of the tangents just to the left and just to the right of the given point are unequal.

And this reason for being non - differentiable is pretty clear for such diagrams.

[image]

**But what if the length of the sharp point increases ?**

By the term **length of the sharp point** , I mean to say that the two sides of the curve just near the sharp point are pretty close as given in the figure (not a good picture though) .

[image]

The tangents on the left and on the right of the point will eventually have the same slope as we increase the length of the sharp point.

**So does that mean that the function will become differentiable at that point ?**

Comment: "The tangents on the left and on the right will eventually have the same slope as we increase the length of the sharp point." Following up on this idea here, what number do you think the slope of the tangents will approach?

Comment: @Elliot Yu  sorry.. I forgot about the orientation of the graph... My question was not for vertical ones .. what if the sharp point was along the horizontal ?? Check out the edit

Comment: The curve with a horizontal cusp cannot be the graph of a function though, since there would be more than one values corresponding to each input.

Comment: Just a comment on possible incorrect reasoning at the beginning, or if not, then very misleading wording. You said your teacher said that functions with sharp corners at a point are non-differentiable at the point. However, this doesn't logically imply that the ONLY way a function can be non-differentiable at a point is to have a sharp corner, but your next sentence suggests that you think this. Moreover, this is not just a matter of incorrect abstract logical reasoning, but in fact there exist functions without a sharp corner at a point that are non-differentiable at the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer to the question before the edit that rotated the hand-drawn diagram through $90^\circ$:**

No. If the tangents tend to a vertical line at a point $x$, then the function is not differentiable at $x$ - the limit that defines the derivative of at $x$ is required to be finite. The equation $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ (for $-1 \le x \le 1$) gives an example which is not differentiable at $x = \pm 1$ (the graph is a semi-circle). This is true no matter how you extend the graph to the right of $1$ or the left of $-1$. If you extend the graph by taking $y = -\sqrt{1- (x - 2)^2}$ for $1 \le x \le 3$, the resulting function does not have a sharp corner at $x = 1$, but is still not differentiable at $x = 1$, so your teacher's remark is a bit of an oversimplification.

**Answer after the edit**

As mentioned in the comments the hand-drawn diagram is now not the graph of a single-valued function. The usual idea of differentiability is confined to single-valued functions. If the slope tends to $0$ at $x$, then there is no problem and the derivative is $0$ at $x$. E.g., consider these examples: $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $y = x^2$ or $y = x^3$ all at $x = 0$.

**Further remarks**

Nonetheless, your teacher's remark remains an oversimplification. Here are some other ways in which a function can fail to be differentiable at a point. First of all a function is is not differentiable at $x$ if it is not continuous at $x$: The function $f$ defined by:

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l@{\quad}l} 0 & \mbox{if $x \le 0$} \\
1 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{array}\right.
$$

is not differentiable at $x = 0$ even though the slopes of the tangents as $x$ tends to $0$ all line up nicely.

Things get stranger if you consider a function like:
$$
g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l@{\quad}l} x \sin \frac{1}{x} & \mbox{if $x \neq 0$} \\
0 & \mbox{if $x = 0$}\end{array}\right.
$$

For $g$ the slopes of the tangents as $x$ approaches $0$ oscillate without approaching any limit, so $g$ is not differentiable at $0$. However, the function $h$ defined by:

$$
h(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l@{\quad}l} x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} & \mbox{if $x \neq 0$} \\
0 & \mbox{if $x = 0$}\end{array}\right.
$$

is differentiable at $x = 0$: the slopes of the tangents oscillate but do approach the limit $0$ and so $h$ is differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: I apologise.. I did not notice the fact that the sharp point was vertical .. 
I know making an edit after getting an answer is not favoured on this site but  I have to make the edit cuz I can't post another question for the same thing..

Comment: If you make changes that affect existing answers, then it's good to flag what you've changed.

Comment: Now you have rotated the second figure, it is no longer the graph of a function. See other comments. Apart from that, it is OK for the derivative to be $0$, so the tangents are horizontal,. E.g. take $x=0$ in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Turned the way described, if the point were extended infinitely then it would be differentiable, but not in the way that the author hoped. Essentially, it would become an implicit function, composed of two explicit functions, essentially never connecting (except at infinity).